# Can a regular expression distinguishes a string that contains constant number of lengths of each clause in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry, my English is poor. Here are examples:

```
'000,111,123,486' //true
'000' //true
'000,111,123,486,781' //true
'000,111,123,486,781,471' //true
'868,1,662' //false because the length of the second clause is 1.
'000,' //false because there is only 1 clause so the comma is not allowed.
```

I need a regex for matching this pattern. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself.

```
/^(\d{3})(,\d{3})*$/
```